# Implicit Differentiation: Multiple Solutions?

Tags: calculus

Question:

Find the coordinates of those points on the curve given by the equation:

$\ x^2-0.25xy+y^2=16 $

at which the tangent line has slope 1.

Implicitly derived:$\ \frac{(-2x+0.25y)}{(2y-0.25x)} $

The book talked something about solving for y (from the original equation):

$\ \pm \sqrt{-x^2+0.25xy+16}$

then substituting it back into the implicitly derived equation and solving, but I am not sure that is going to work or else it is going to be very cumbersome. Anyone know how to solve this, perhaps in a simpler (possibly more correct) fashion? Thanks!

P.S. I spent 30mins figuring out the mathTex stuff so it looks pretty, it was the least I could do I suppose? Only for all you picky math geniuses who are going to help me! :)

Comment: Try polar coordinates $x = r cos(t)$ and $y = r sin(t)$. Solve for $r$ and you'll obtain a function of $t$. This function I think will not be difficult to differentiate. I'd didn't check it, so I write a comment and not an answer...

Comment: It would be good to make your implicit derivative an equation by putting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the other side of an equals sign.  But good on you for trying, showing what you have done, and working on $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an equation of degree 2, the curve in question is a [conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). Looking at the coefficients, it's probably an ellipse. (The criterion for that is that the quadratic form should always be positive.)

The equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. In other words, a reflection at the line $y=x$ will map the ellipse to itself. This also means that the line $y=x$ is also a main axis.

[image: Ellipse has main axis $y=x$]

*Coincidentally*, the question also asks for a tangent with *exactly the same slope* as the main axis. This can only happen at the points where the other main axis intersects the ellipse. In our case, the other axis is the line $y=-x$.

Hence, the points in question have the form $(x,-x)$ and can be obtained by solving the equation

$$ x^2 + 1/4·x^2 + x^2 = 16 $$

i.e. $x = \pm\sqrt{64/9} = \pm 8/3$.

Comment: Thanks, you even drew me a nice picture! Makes so much more sense now! Stupid calculus books make everything so complicated...

Comment: Of course, I didn't actually use calculus to solve the problem. :-) If the tangent slope would have been anything other than 1, then my argument wouldn't work, but the implicit differentiation thing would still work.

Answer (score 2):

You have already implicitly derived the expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You can set that equal to 1 and simplify to get $x = -y$. Substitute that in the original equation and you have a quadratic that can be easily solved.

I got the solutions $x = \pm 8/3$ and $y = \mp 8/3$.

The book seems to be making a big deal out of a very simple question.